# VIM, Automatic formatting, Code-Guidelines, C++

Tags: c++, vim

I want to be able to automatically format code for the following rules using vim:

Rule 1):  If expressions which are must be indeneted with 3 spaces. Example:

```
if(a &&
   b)
```

(Note: b has three space-indent relative to the parent if, note that current vim behavior is 4)

Rule 2): parameters separated by space. Example:

```
 function_call(a, b, c);
```

Rule 3): No space between assignment operators. Example:

```
int a=x;
```

Rule 4):  Reference/dereference operator is attached to variable name not type. Example:

int &x = b;

Where possible, I want vim to do this stuff automatically as I am typing, however if this not possible, identifying formatting that is counter to the above rules (by marking them as errors)  will also be helpful.

Comment: I've always worked with 1) setting vim's indentation options and 2) using a linter to check code style, usually every time I `:w`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set auto-indentation rules in a custom indent file. Check out examples in the "indent" directory, somewhere like `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent`, or in the Vim [source code distribution](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/d07969093a9b3051511c478d71c36de6fc33c0d6/runtime/indent).

You can set error highlighting rules in a [custom syntax file](https://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/vi/vi-4.shtml). Find examples in the "syntax" directory, somewhere like `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax`, or again in the Vim [source code distribution](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/d07969093a9b3051511c478d71c36de6fc33c0d6/runtime/syntax). Here's an example for JSON files:

```
" Syntax: Decimals smaller than one should begin with 0 (so .1 should be 0.1).
syn match   jsonNumError  "\:\@<=[[:blank:]\r\n]*\zs\.\d\+"
```

If you want to actually re-format code automatically as you go you might need a special plugin like [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) and/or an external tool like [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding indenting, and so on, check the options [`:h 'sw'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sw%27), [`:h 'cindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cindent%27), [`:h 'cinoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cinoptions%27)...

Regarding where spaces and newlines shall be inserted,

- For code already typed, clang-format is indeed the best way to go to reformat code. There is a plugin for vim.
- For snippets, brackets and so on, lately I've worked on a plugin aimed at formatting text inserted by other plugins. Excesivelly inspired, I'm named the core plugin [lh-style](http://lh-style.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest). It's used by [mu-template](http://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) (my snippet/templating plugin), and [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets).
- For other stuff you'll want to reformat on the fly, it'll be a little bit more complex. May be lh-style could help, I don't know, I haven't given much though on the subject yet.

  For instance, outside comments and strings, `=` shall be expanded into :

  1. itself after a `[` (lamdbas),
  2. `<BS>=<space>`, after `=`, `>`, `<`, `!` followed by a space
  3. `<space>=<space>` otherwise

  EDIT: I got it all wrong, it does exactly the contrary of what you're looking for.

  It'd be something like:

  ```
  " ftplugin/c/mymappings.vim
  function! s:InsertExpr(char) abort
    let col  = col('.')
    let line = getline('.')

    let syn = synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col-1,1),'name')
    if syn =~? 'comment\|string\|character\|doxygen'
      return a:key
    endif

    let lcut = getline('.')[: col-2]
    let before =
          \   lcut =~ '[=<>!] $'       ? "\<bs>"
          \ : lcut =~ "[=<>![ \t\n]$"  ? ''
          \ :                            ' '
    let after = line[col-1] =~ "[ \t\n\\]]" ? '' : ' '
    return before.a:char.after
  endfunction

  inoremap <buffer> <expr> = <sid>InsertExpr('=')
  inoremap <buffer> <expr> < <sid>InsertExpr('<')
  inoremap <buffer> <expr> > <sid>InsertExpr('>')
  ```